# Height Transition Not Working CSS

Tags: css, css-transitions

My codes are pretty simple yet I've failed to get how a transition works and how it doesn't work on my HTML right here:

```
<div id="footer">
    <div id="footer1">
        <p> This should be a footer </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my CSS

```
        #footer {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: black;
        min-width: 100%;
        font-family: Agency FB;
        transition: width 3s;
    }
    #footer1 {
        text-align: center;
        color: #4e4e4e;

    }
    #footer:hover {

        opacity: .8;
        color: white;
        height: 100px;
    }
```

I don't see anything wrong with my code. That or I'm still inexperienced. Thanks!

Comment: The `#footer` element requires a fixed numeric height to begin animating, it won't transition from `auto` to `100px`.

Comment: try this: https://jsfiddle.net/maky/bgeLbpd9/

Comment: Here some good source to learn [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) and [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: black;
    min-width: 100%;
    font-family: Agency FB;
    transition: height 3s;
    height: 50px;
}
#footer1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #4e4e4e;

}
#footer:hover {

    opacity: .8;
    color: white;
    height: 100px;
}
```

If it doesn't work please tell me

Comment: Oh God... I'm so blind. I found out anyway but what took me longer to realize was that the "live" viewer of DreamWeaver CS6, for some reason, doesn't play the animation. Thanks anyway, I'll make sure to test on Chrome next time XD

Comment: @Dinklefarts haha struggles

Answer (score 0):

```css
  #footer {
        position: absolute;
        bottom:0;
        background-color: black;
        min-width: 100%;
        height:50px;
        font-family: Agency FB;
        transition: width 3s, height 1s, transform 1s;
    }
    #footer1 {
        text-align: center;
        color: #4e4e4e;
    }
    #footer:hover {
        opacity: .8;
        color: white;
        height: 100px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="footer">
    <div id="footer1">
        <p> This should be a footer </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Just play around with the values of `transition: width 3s, height 1s, transform 1s;`

Cheers!